# Quoting all text fields in CSV

Tags: .net, csv

What problems may arise if I were to quote all text fields in quotes?

I'm making a couple methods that take in a [System.Data.DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and will save the contents into a CSV formatted file. I'm wondering for the sake of argument, will quoting all values from the iterated row of type string be acceptable? From all my research everything says to quote values that contain a delimiter. I know I could go further and check if the string contains said delimiter but for simplicity I am checking type and quoting anything that is a string, and leaving the rest alone e.g. decimal, int, etc.

This process also applies to the column names, will I be OK to always quote them as well?

Answer (score 0):

I would be more careful then that. for instance, if your delimiter is " and the string is something like 1 foot 2"  then your encapsulated string becomes "1 foot 2 ""  which will break most further actions you would do with the string.

Comment: Ignore my last comment if you saw it, I just noticed I read your question wrong. How common is it to find a quote (") as a delimiter for a standard CSV format? I saw somewhere someone else asking about CSV and using a quote as a delimiter and thought it was strange. These methods don't give control over delimiter, strictly uses a comma.